# How to properly align the axis line and labels using axis() in R

Tags: r, axis

I am plotting the distribution of jobs in a population, and thus the x-axis is a categorical variable. I managed to label the x-axis with the names of the categories, but they don't align with the actual plot. I'm not sure what syntax to use to align.

The data and code:

```
d<-structure(c(5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 12L, 6L, 12L, 
3L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 
7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
12L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
12L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
11L, 7L, 12L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 
12L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
12L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
12L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 
12L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 
6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 
7L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 
2L, 6L, 11L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 11L, 2L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 2L, 
6L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
12L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 
12L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
12L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
10L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 
8L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 3L, 
6L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 
6L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 
4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 
6L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 
12L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 2L, 
2L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Construction", 
"Education or healthcare", "Finance", "Government/Military", 
"Legal or business", "Leisure and hospitality", "Manufacturing", 
"Media and telecommunications", "Mining and logging", "Transport and utilities", 
"Unemployed", "Wholesale or retail"), class = "factor")

#d

Occs<-c("Legal or business", "Education or healthcare", "Government/Military", "Transport and utilities", "Manufacturing", "Leisure and hospitality", "Finance", "Wholesale or retail", "Unemployed", "Construction", "Media and telecommunications", "Mining and logging")
#print(Occs)

#plot(d$Occupation)
plot(d, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=1:12, labels=Occs, las=3, cex.axis=1) #, cex.axis=0.35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is a factor, which means that via the somewhat labyrinthian S3 method dispatch for `plot` you end up calling `plot.factor`, which in turn calls `barplot(table(d))`. Handily, `barplot` returns the values of the midpoints of the bars:

```
p <- plot(d, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=p, labels=Occs, las=3, cex.axis=1) #, cex.axis=0.35
```

Comment: Thanks, @joran! This works, except the actual x-axis doesn't contact the y-axis anymore. Any suggestions on this front?

Comment: @Atticus29 The axes never did meet, so I don't know what you're talking about. In any case, it doesn't make any sense for the x axis to extend any further for a bar plot, because the axis has no meaning except directly under the bars. If you want to draw a box around everything you could try calling `bax()` but I think that looks terrible.